# jquery add remove inputs

Tags: jquery, input, addition

My jQuery right now works perfectly when I use it to perform creation, and deletion, of textboxes. But the code does not work properly when I decide to allow users to edit them after they submit and the same code upon modification does not work anymore.

My rules are such that there needs to be a minimum of **2 iterations boxes and 1 task in each iteration**, anything less than that would cause the jQuery to disable my remove iteration and minus task button respectively.

Now my codes cannot seem to allow a user to reduce a task even though there is more than 1 task in the iteration and the remove iteration button is forever disabled, despite starting off with, say, 5 iterations.

I cannot remove the 'disable' at the beginning because a user may end up with zero task if he has only filled in one task, so I can only remove the 'disable' once the `if`-loop proves that there is more than the minimum required.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6fnq2/1/) is my jQuery code, can somebody please help and give some advice? :)) Thanks in advance!

PS: `$('.plus')` refers to my add task class button, `$('.moins')` refers to my minus task class button, `$('#removeIteration')` and `$('#addIteration')` both represent remove iteration and add iteration respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give us some context on your problem (what is it exactly your code is supposed to do, and how is it doing it right now (a rough description of your approach is enough), and paste only the *relevant* code *in your question*. Right now it is not clear at all what you mean with iteration, as you do not explain what your iterations are supposed to be doing.

--edit 1

I see you have split up the question in paragraphs, very good. Please keep making it better by providing the context.

--edit 2

I see you use parent().parent().parent(). This is rather inflexible code. You should use .closest('query describing the parent you are looking for').

Instead of 'return false;' you should use 'event.preventDefault();' and edit the lines like

```
$(".moins").live("click", function() {
```

to

```
$(".moins").live("click", function(event) {
```

Comment: i already explained at the beginning of the question. the codes are all relevant. Which part of it do you not understand? The iterations are supposed to contain textboxes that contain user's task..just think simple. You have an iteration box that contain a number of tasks. you can choose to increase or decrease the number of iterations or tasks but the minimum you are allowed to go is, 2 iterations left with a minimum of one task in each iteration. Get it?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not (perhaps I'm just being stupid here). Can you please describe, in the first paragraph of your question, what your program is supposed to be doing. Something like: *I am creating a website for a bank. The users have bank-accounts which I display with textboxes, it can be one or more. The users can than deposit money in their accounts using checkboxes.* (This example is complete nonsense, but please write a short intro like that)

Comment: The thing is: you are asking a question here. When you ask a question you should try making it as easy as possible to understand. Right now, it is rather hard.

Comment: I have looked at your code again. Without the html it is virtually impossible to answer your question. I do have some remarks, see the edit in my question.

Comment: @pivotal developer - This question is quite difficult to answer as-is. Please consider expanding it, and being a bit more understanding in comments. I've starred this and will follow up.